# BigQuery: does it support UDAF?

Tags: google-bigquery, user-defined-functions

I guess BigQuery doesn't support UDAF since all I can find was about UDF. Does BigQuery support UDAF? If not, is there any way to run a UDF on aggregated result somehow? Maybe by using ARRAY_AGG?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use ARRAY_AGG to model a UDAF. As an example, you can do:

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION AggX(arr ARRAY<INT64>) AS (
  (SELECT SUM(x * x) FROM UNNEST(arr) AS x)
);

SELECT id, AggX(ARRAY_AGG(x)) AS result
FROM dataset.table
GROUP BY id
```

Depending on what sort of logic you want to implement, you can even have the function take an `ARRAY<STRUCT<...>>` with whatever columns you want the function to operate on, and use `ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(...))` to build the input to it.